# When we have multiple languages in a movie and need to convert particular language (E-ac3) to AC3(Dolby digital) using FFMPEG. How?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion

I need an FFMPEG command. Below is the screen shot of Movie codec details and that contains 4 languages (all are 6 channels).

[image: Plz go through this link to see Movie codec details]

Comment: What commands have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people that are interested in computers and are willing to share their experience and knowledge with others. If you can tell us what you already have tried, we migth be able to help you find the error in that particular command.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your replay...

As of now am tried with this below command


ffmpeg -i "www.1TamilMV.bar - Annaatthe (2021) HQ HDRip - 1080p - HEVC - (DD+5.1 - 192Kbps) [Tam + Tel + Mal + Hin + Kan] - ESub.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a:1 -codec copy -acodec ac3 "Annaatthe (2021) Telugu 1080p (5.1 DOLBY DTS).mkv"

but  I am getting bellow error in CMD window..

Comment: File 'Annaatthe (2021) Telugu 1080p (5.1 DOLBY DTS).mkv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (eac3 (native) -> ac3 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska @ 00000272e7ac8640] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:2 --
Conversion failed!

Answer (score 0):

You may use FFmpeg [mapping](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) notations.

Here is an example for copy (the video) and the first and second audio streams and re-encode the third audio stream with `ac3` codec:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mkv -map 0:v:0 -c:v:0 copy -map:a:0 0:a:0 -c:a:0 copy -map:a:1 0:a:1 -c:a:1 copy -map:a:2 0:a:2 -c:a:2 ac3 out.mkv
```

---

Mapping example:

- `-map:a:0 0:a:0` maps the first audio stream of the input to the first audio stream of the output. (the first `0` in `0:a:0` is the index of the input file `in.mkv`).
- `-c:a:0 copy` applies codec `copy` to the first output audio stream.

---

Testing:
Create input with 3 `eac3` audio stream (applies 3 languages):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=5.1:sample_rate=48000 -map:v 0:v -map:a:0 1:a -map:a:1 1:a -map:a:2 1:a -metadata:s:a:0 language=dut -metadata:s:a:1 language=ita -metadata:s:a:2 language=eng -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -c:a eac3 -t 10 in.mkv
```

Note:
The `anullsrc` is silent, so I can't asses the converted audio quality.
I assume the quality of the output audio is out of the scope of the question.

Execute the conversion command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mkv -map 0:v:0 -c:v:0 copy -map:a:0 0:a:0 -c:a:0 copy -map:a:1 0:a:1 -c:a:1 copy -map:a:2 0:a:2 -c:a:2 ac3 out.mkv
```

---

Testing the output using MediaInfo tool:

```
General
...

Video
ID                                       : 1
...

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : E-AC-3
Format/Info                              : Enhanced AC-3
Commercial name                          : Dolby Digital Plus
Codec ID                                 : A_EAC3
Duration                                 : 10 s 16 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 448 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : 5 ms
Stream size                              : 548 KiB (32%)
Writing library                          : Lavc58.91.100 eac3
Language                                 : Dutch
Service kind                             : Complete Main
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : E-AC-3
Format/Info                              : Enhanced AC-3
Commercial name                          : Dolby Digital Plus
Codec ID                                 : A_EAC3
Duration                                 : 10 s 16 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 448 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : 5 ms
Stream size                              : 548 KiB (32%)
Writing library                          : Lavc58.91.100 eac3
Language                                 : Italian
Service kind                             : Complete Main
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No

Audio #3
ID                                       : 4
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Commercial name                          : Dolby Digital
Codec ID                                 : A_AC3
Duration                                 : 10 s 16 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 448 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 548 KiB (32%)
Writing library                          : Lavc58.91.100 ac3
Language                                 : English
Service kind                             : Complete Main
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No
```

---

In case you also want to convert the audio from 6 channels to 2 channels, you have to apply conversion filter for the specific stream (use Google to find an example).